# What's difference between Style Theme and Decoration in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm really Confused about the difference between style property and Decoration . .
Both can change how Ui looks like

Comment: To answer your question correctly, can you share any example?

Answer (score 0):

Style is usually applied to TextFields or some button widgets, decoration is a property of Containers. On my sight, style is usually wide (global) thing, decoration is a partial thing.

P.S. Compare: *These decorations (concrete) were implemented in victorian style (abstract)*.